# Jquery- On an Ajax response create row and group them based on column value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I need to call a Rest API using Ajax. Based on the Ajax response i have to add a row to the HTML table. I am able to achieve this using Jquery.

Now, i want to group the rows based on a column in the Ajax response and show them as different groups based on that.
 I mean to say... ajax call get me data required for a row, when i am adding it to the table, it has to go to a corresponding group based on column value... How to achieve this?

Any help and ideas are most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use a multidimensional array that contains all of the values for the table.  Then, each time your AJAX returns you can add the new values to the array and recreate the table with the correct grouping.

Comment: This is probably going to be the best approach unless he has control over the API in which case the smartest move would be to have the API send the data already sorted.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  But this prevents the server from having to send over the entire dataset each time there's an update/new row, which is a perk.

Comment: I dont have any control over the API. Creating an array seems to be good, but each API call is taking more time... So, Time to create the Array takes more time and i dont want to make the user wait for so long to see the page. Any other approaches?

Comment: Can you request multiple elements at once?  Or is there any way to begin pre-loading the data, perhaps while the user is on a different page?

Comment: @maxmcc- I dont have any control over the API or on the ajax call to return more data. I will try on your approach- each time your AJAX returns you can add the new values to the array and recreate the table with the correct grouping. just thinking... rearranging the rows over kills the user experience on the page.

Comment: Okay.  Then if there's no way for you to anticipate the data that will need to be loaded and begin preloading it while the user is doing something else, you might be stuck with using a loading spinner :-/


You can have the table redraw itself after every API return, so it will populate on the fly, as the user watches.  That combined with a loading spinner might be enough to keep your user patient.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the API developers?  They might have an idea for a solution, or they may take your advice and add additional functionality.